# Sort lists in python based on a rule

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

I have lists like:

```
['pt=media:song', 'class=song', 'object=mp3']
['class=text','pt=transaction:email', 'object=email']
['category=where','pt=text:where','class:question']
['object:mp4','class=movie', 'pt=media:movie']
```

I want to sort them such that I always have the fields starting from `"pt="` first and the rest of them sorted in alphabetical order.

so the result would be:

```
['pt=media:song','class=song', 'object=mp3']
['pt=transaction:email','class=text', 'object=email']
['pt=text:where','category=where','class:question'] 
['pt=media:movie','class=movie','object:mp4']
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: There are no dates or anything else in your lists. What on earth does "chronological order" mean in this case?

Comment: Your sample output uses *ascending **lexicographical** order*. For text, that's alphabetical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a tuple per item:

```
sorted(yourlist, key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('pt='), x))
```

This will sort any value starting with `pt=` first (as `False` sorts before `True`), any other value is sorted lexicographically (which means the same as alphabetical when applied to text).

Demo:

```
>>> samples = [
...     ['pt=media:song','class=song', 'object=mp3'],
...     ['class=text','pt=transaction:email', 'object=email'],
...     ['category=where','pt=text:where','class:question'],
...     ['object:mp4','class=movie', 'pt=media:movie'],
... ]
>>> for sample in samples:
...     print sorted(sample, key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('pt='), x))
... 
['pt=media:song', 'class=song', 'object=mp3']
['pt=transaction:email', 'class=text', 'object=email']
['pt=text:where', 'category=where', 'class:question']
['pt=media:movie', 'class=movie', 'object:mp4']
```