# Sorting lists based on conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have lists like:

```
['pt=media:song', 'c=100','class=song', 'object=mp3']
['class=text','pt=transaction:email','c=90','object=email']
['c=97','category=where','pt=text:where','class:question']
['object:mp4','class=movie', 'pt=media:movie','c=56']
```

I want to sort them such that I always have the fields starting from `'c='` appear first, `"pt="` appear second and the rest of them sorted in alphabetical order.

so the result would be:

```
['c=100','pt=media:song','class=song', 'object=mp3']
['c=90','pt=transaction:email','class=text', 'object=email']
['c=97','pt=text:where','category=where','class:question'] 
['c=56','pt=media:movie','class=movie','object:mp4']
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21762295/538284

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort lists in python based on a rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762177/sort-lists-in-python-based-on-a-rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort with a `tuple` key whose first two elements check `c=` and `pt=`:

```
.sort(key=lambda x:(not x.startswith('c='), not x.startswith('pt='), x))
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will put the `item` starting with the specified string(s) at the start, then use `sorted` to put the rest in the right order:

```
def rearrange(lst, s):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item.startswith(s[0]):
            if len(s) == 1:
                return [item] + sorted(lst[:index] + lst[index+1:])
            else:
                return [item] + rearrange(lst[:index] + lst[index+1:], s[1:])
```

For example:

```
>>> rearrange(['object:mp4','class=movie', 'pt=media:movie','c=56'], 
              ("c=", "pt="))
['c=56', 'pt=media:movie', 'class=movie', 'object:mp4']
```

If no items start with the appropriate string(s), it will `return None`.

Answer (score 1):

This will have your two specials in right order followed by rest in alphabetical:

```
In [212]: l = ['object:mp4','class=movie', 'pt=media:movie','c=56']

In [213]: specials = [i for i in l if i.startswith("c=") or i.startswith("pt=")]

In [214]: sorted(specials) + sorted(set(l).difference(specials))
Out[214]: ['c=56', 'pt=media:movie', 'class=movie', 'object:mp4']
```