# Sort by a specific word and by alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I'm using python 2.7. I have a list of apps that I want to sort.
My problem is this: I have a specific word that I need to be on top of the list and then rest will come.

my list is like this:

- Appname1
- Appname2
- Appname2Bootstrap
- Appname3
- Appname3Bootstrap

Now I used this code to sort by alphabetical order

```
with open(filename) as
sortedFile:
    sortedFile = sortedFile.readlines()
    sortedFile.sort()
```

I have no idea how to make it sort first by using the word "Boostrap"

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: You could write a custom sort function and pass that as a parameter, see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: My expected output is:
* Appname2Bootstrap
* Appname3Bootstrap
* Appname1
* Appname2
* Appname3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762177/sort-lists-in-python-based-on-a-rule?rq=1) to a different question, you can set a function for the key to be sorted on:

```
from __future__ import print_function

items = ['Appname1', 'Appname2', 'Appname2Bootstrap', 'Appname3', 'Appname3Bootstrap']
items_sorted = sorted(items, key=lambda x: (not x.endswith('Bootstrap'), x))

print('Got the sorted items: {}'.format(items_sorted))
```

This will put the two items with "Bootstrap" at the beginning of your sorted list.